# Actionbarの左上の戻るボタンの制御について

Tags: android

ActionBarActivityのActionBar左上の戻るボタン(<)を押した時に、前の画面に戻るように指示を出したいのですが、どのように書き換えるべきでしょうか。 
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
    switch (item.getItemId()) { 
        case R.id.home: 
            finish(); 
    } 
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`R.id.home`を`android.R.id.home`に変更すればうまくいくと思います。

Comment: 上手くいきました！ありがとうございます。